# regex remove empty space except carriage returns

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this `regex` that strips out extra white space but the problem is that it gets rid of carriage returns.
`var str = str.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ")`

How can I get rid of those empty space while preserving carriage returns? 
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
var str = str.replace(/((?!\r)\s){2,}/g, " ")
```

Or if you want to preserve both carriage returns and linefeeds, something like this would work:

```
var str = str.replace(/((?![\r\n])\s){2,}/g, " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly specify space character set:

```
> '1    \r\n    2    \r\n'.replace(/[ \t\f\v]{2,}/g, ' ')
"1 
 2 
"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex to only trim multiple spaces to one:

```
str = str.replace(/ {2,}/g, " ");
```

`\s` matches spaces, tabs and newlines.